# How to get absolute url in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, href

In my view I'm giving a URL out like this:

```
<td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #f3ad44" align="center">
    <a class="actions" href="<%= item.URL  %>">www...</a>
</td>
```

My problem is that `item.URL` has a value like: `www.hello.com` but when i click on it from webpage it navigates to `http://localhost:64075/www.hello.com`.

How can I avoid of using localhost, and actually navigate to `http://www.hello.com`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to prefix the url with the proper protocol (such as `http://`), either inside `item.URL` or in the markup: `[...] href="http://<%= item.URL  %>">[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #f3ad44" align="center">
     <a class="actions" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://<%= item.URL  %>'); return false;">www...</a> 
</td> 

<td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #f3ad44" align="center">
     <a class="actions" href="#" onclick="window.location='http://<%= item.URL  %>'; ">www...</a> 
</td>
```